# How to use Value Change Listener to entire form or group of events

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dom-events, valuechangelistener

In JSF we can use

`valueChangeListener` attribute

or

```
<f:valueChangeListener type=""/>
```

to listen for ValueChange Events for Individual components.

> Is there any way that i can apply the ValueChangeListner to group of
>   components or entire form?

**Edit:**

> The basic idea is, There is a huge form of around 30
>   components[input-texts,text-areas,select-many-menu,select-one-menu.....]
>   and some of them will be pre-populated.
>   I want to notify the user whenever there is value change in any one component of this entire
>   form.

Comment: Kishor, what exactly do you need this for ? What's your concrete problem ? I'm only asking because there might be another solution to your problem ? [Multiple component validation](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/multi-components-validator-in-jsf-2-0/) perhaps ?

Answer (score -1):

No. You can apply the same value change listener for multiple components, and you will need to handle it programatically

Comment: I know this is old (as JSF), but your answer just provides weak clues for research. Can you please add some steps or links, even a code-example __how to__ "apply the same value change listener" or "handle it programatically".